# How to create dictionaries according to for loop in Python?

Tags: python, list, selenium, loops, dictionary

I am scraping blockchain address transaction data from a website and I want to create a dictionary with all transactions for each address.

Each url shows all transactions for a single address.

I would like to know what the correct structure for creating the dictionaries per address is and how to append the information into each dictionary.

My current structure/pseudo-code is the following:

```
for address in addresses:
    yield ('https://cchain.explorer.avax.network/address/' + address +
           '/tokens/' + token_address + '/token-transfers')

all_txs = {
    for address in addresses:
        txs = {
                {
                    'amount': '250',
                    'type': 'inflow'
                },
                {
                    'amount': '1000'
                    'type': 'outflow'
                }
        }
}
```

The actual amount and type data are examples, but they look exactly like what I want to have.

The problem with my structure is that it does not show the address in the all_txs dictionary. I don't know how to run the address loop within the dictionary.

Comment: Where should the address go? Should it be another field in each inner dictionary, or the key for its inner dictionary in the outer dictionary? If the former, what should the keys be?

Comment: the txs dictionary should go inside the address. Basically, 'address' would be the parent dictionary of txs. And again, there would be more than one address dictionary under all_txs. Order: all_txs -> address -> txs (key:value)

Comment: @LuizScheuer what is txs supposed to be? A dictionary? and how do you obtain it for a specific address?

Comment: Yep, as above, txs is supposed to be a dictionary. The information that will be added to the txs dictionary (the 'amount' and the 'type') will have to be scraped from the website. Each url is a different address. Each address has multiple transactions. And each transaction has an amount and a type. I wan to iterate through each website/address, then, inside each website/address, through every transaction, then, record the amount and type of each transaction. I just don't know how to build a dictionary and list structure to append all this info.